# Google Earth Engine, get a List of Bands

Tags: google-earth-engine, list, band

I want to Automate Band selection for all bands. Therefore a List of the Bands is needed. This didn´t work:

```
ee.List(image.get('bands'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all the bands in an image by using:

```
var band_names = image.bandNames()
```

also see here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagebandnames